# Socket.EndReceiveFrom seemingly doing nothing C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I have a snippet of code which is supposed to receive udp pacets asynchronously and convert what it receives into a string for my program to compute. The thing is I was able at some point to make it break within the operation via breakpoints and see that what it received was just 0, but now I cant even make the program break there, but that shouldn't be an issue because all things considered it should be receiving the udp data packets without an issue.

Here is the code:

Method that starts the AsyncCallback:

```
    private static void ReceiveLogin()
    { 
        string l = string.Empty;
        IPEndPoint senden = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 13200);
        byte[] k = new byte[50];
        EndPoint address = (EndPoint)senden;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
        WinSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(k, 0, k.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref address,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallbackLogin), null);
    }
```

The AsyncCallback:

```
    private async static void ReceiveCallbackLogin(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        string l = string.Empty;
        byte[] k = new byte[50];
        int bytes = 0;
        IPEndPoint senden = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 13200);
        EndPoint address = (EndPoint)senden;


            bytes = WinSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref address);


            l = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(k, 0, bytes);


            if (l != string.Empty)
            {

                if (l == "Misserfolg")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fehler bei der Anmeldung, bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Eingaben!", "Anmeldungsfehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    return;
                }
                else if (l == "Erfolg")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Anmeldung erfolgreich!", "Anmeldung", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return;
                }

                if (bytes <= 10)
                {
                    WinSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(k, 0, k.Length, 0, ref address, ReceiveCallbackLogin, WinSocket);
                }
            }

    }
```

Also here is what calls the first Method:

```
    private void LogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = $"Login | {LogNamFeld.Text} | {LogPassFeld.Text}";            
        Byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login);
        RetryTimer.Enabled = true;

        WinSocket.SendTo(bytes, SocketFlags.None, seitenad);
        Login();

    }

    private void Login()
    {
        
        RegisterTimer.Enabled = true;
        ReceiveLogin();
    }
```

The Socket is also already bound to the right IP address and snychronously receives perfectly fine, but asynchronously seems to be a bit of a problem, would be greatly appreciated if anybody could help me fix that.

Kind Regards

Ekoboy